# Where I can get NMEA data dump of GLONASS or GPS simulator?

Tags: gps, open-source, nmea

For my graduation work and [my open source project](https://github.com/Dronnikkl/GNSS-spoofing-detection) about detection of «spoofing» GPS and GLONASS signal I need NMEA data dump of GPS/GLONASS receiver which receive signals from GLONASS or GPS simulator.

Where I can get NMEA logs which include $GPGSV strings? 
Because I analyze levels of satellites signal and try to detect «spoofing».

I have GPS Receiver, and have experience to dump NMEA from it, so I have Real signal. But i have not dumps of spoofed signal which my GPS receiver can get from GPS simulator which generate spoofed signals, so I can't make charts and software test. [In one of related works](https://github.com/Dronnikkl/GNSS-spoofing-detection) discussed that if we have C/N0 values of spoofed signal we can detect spoofing. In NMEA specification C/N0 is SNR value of satellite. Maybe I can generate spoofed signal programatticaly, but I think it will not be a clean experiment.

Comment: Cool project, but there is absolutely no way to give you any answer because we don't even know what system or language you're using.

Comment: It's not a problem to use any language. I want to make github open source project. For example C language and create functions for detection of spoofing. But without a simulator dumps I am not sure what can develop it and algorithms that I found work. Do You have any dumps or have any GPS GLONASS Simulator?

Comment: Not off hand.  I recommend just plugging in a GPS and getting this data yourself.  It's easy to do.  You typically just need to capture a serial port.

Comment: Yes, I have GPS Receiver, and have experience to dump NMEA from it. But i have not dumps of spoofed signal which my GPS receiver can get from GPS simulator which generate spoofed signals, so I can't make charts and software test. In one of related works http://radionavlab.ae.utexas.edu/images/stories/files/papers/unmannedCapture.pdf discussed that if we have C/N0 values of spoofed signal we can detect spoofing. In NMEA specification C/N0 is SNR value of satellite . Maybe I mistaken, that I need to have Real and Spoofed dumps to make clean experiment and to test my detection software?

Comment: It sounds like you do need spoofed GPS logs.  For that, you will likely have to spoof them yourself.  I have heard of folks doing this in the lab with SDRs, but do not know much about it, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can recommend some other resources to post my project and to find people working in labs or who have simulators?

Comment: Then you should at least tell where you live, I know two companies who have an simulator. (But I  am not sure if they are available, and they have developped their own Anti - spoofing software, So I am not sure If the want to support)

Answer (score 0):

One part is very simple: To get the NMEA from a GPS chip:

buy a GPS device from Sirf or uBlox.
Then use the free Software uCenter for uBlox device.
For Sirf it is or was called SirfDemo.

I used the Wintec WBT-201 (or similar named) device, which has a uBlox chip.
In uCenter you set the chip to NMEA mode, and enable the GPGSV messages.
Messages will be output to a window or file.

Remains the problem how to get your GPS chip spoofed.

The only way I konw is to use the extremly expensive GPS simulator.
AFAIK There is only company (labsat) with one or two product on the market: maybe  > 20K$. 
You could try to write to that company that they will send you some NMEA records, or you work together with a company that have such a simulator and need anti spoofing software. (If you live in Austria or Germany, you may contact me again, but make first sure that you are well familar how to use uCenter and to record NMEA from a GPS device.)

Comment: I live in Russia,  Moscow.  I call to Russian company which have sumilator for gps and glonass, but they not interested in cooperation. Yes I have one GPS device which can communicate via UART and I have raspberry PI which have UART. I will publish NMEA dump and charts of static and moving positions in a few days. Thank you! I try to write them (labsat).

Comment: Can you share some web resources where I post my questions and attract somebody to my project who can get dumps from simulators?

Comment: I dont know any web resources. This is a very specialized topic, where only(?) companies are interrested, that produce GNNS devices. Practically today it is not possible to spoof a receiver, the labssat device is far to expensive. that any spoofing would make sense. And spoofing does not work in realtime,  Does your professor not have contact to a russian company with a GNSS simulator?